How to translate the days of the week from a date without using str_replace and arrays of day names?
I would find an easiest solution to translate the date directly by php functions (whithout str_replace, arrays of days name and mktime.
Currently I use tables of days name and replace the digit day with the value of table.
In this example I retrieve the months name of year.
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
for ($x = $currentMonth; $x < $currentMonth + 12; $x++) {
    $months[] = date('Y-F-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1));
}
$FrenchMonth = array('Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre');
$EnglishMonth = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

after that I converted each month ("F" date format) in my local language
$twelvemonthsdata = explode('-',$months[$i]);
$twelvemonthsM = $twelvemonthsdata[1];
$twelveFormatMonth = 'F';
$twelvemonthinfrench = str_replace( $EnglishMonth,$FrenchMonth, date($twelveFormatMonth, strtotime($twelvemonthsM)));

I try to use DateTime and IntlDateFormatter but I couldn't find any other way than to convert the result of the "for" loop using strtotime() and use it using DateTime() and intldateformatter().
$currentMonth =  Date('m');

for ($x = $currentMonth; $x < $currentMonth + 12; $x++) {
    $eachmonth = strtotime(Date('Y-F-m', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 1)));

    $tweelvemonths = new DateTime();
    $tweelvemonths->setTimestamp($eachmonth);

    $tweelvemonths_formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR');
    $tweelvemonths_formatter->setTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
    $tweelvemonths_formatter->setPattern('y-MMMM-MM');
    
    $tweelvemonths_formated = $tweelvemonths_formatter->format($tweelvemonths);
    var_dump($tweelvemonths_formated);
}

Is there an easier way or shorter to generate the next 12 months from the current month with the local language using or not strtotime and/or mtkime?

Is there any problem with the "new" approach? I would rate it better than the old one, as you're no longer depending on the static strings for each month's name. Introducing a new language is as simple as changing the locale (as long as it is installed on the system)

No problem with my code, but I would have thought that in 2024 and with the new versions of PHP there would be something shorter than having to first generate the next 12 months from the current one with mktime() (which only works with Date()) and then convert it with intldateformatter().
Knowing all the features and capabilities we've given to DateTime() and Intldateformatter(), I'd have thought these two functions would supplant Date() and mktime().

I don't understand where the change to handling of nulls is relevant to any of this; PHP 8 still accepts it anyway, it just warns you that PHP 9 won't. There's a typo in the first piece of code ($FrenchMonnth should be $FrenchMonth) and I presume a missing for loop for $i. Those will just make the program fail in any PHP version (https://3v4l.org/AqePo or https://3v4l.org/FuWBn), but fix them and the code works exactly the same from PHP 5.2 right up to PHP 8.3: https://3v4l.org/VnDql

I share my own answer.
So without using date() and mtkime() I retrieve the twelve months from current month.
To do that we need to instantiate dateTime before the loop and decrement from 1 month to begin to the current month and not the next generated by the DateTime "modify" property $test->modify('+1 month').
For each loop we increment DateTime to +1 month .
intlDateFormatter takes care of formatting the date and translating it
reference : Day-based ratings for DateTime
$now = Date('m');
$test = new DateTime('now - 1 month');
// or new DateTime('first day of this month - 1 month'); 
// it depends on whether you also manage the day

for ($x = $now ; $x < $now + 12 ; $x++) {
   $test->modify('+1 month');
   $use_formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('fr_FR');
   $use_formatter->setTimeZone('Europe/Paris');
   $use_formatter->setPattern('y-MMMM-MM');
   $formated = $use_formatter->format($test);
   var_dump($formated);
}


Add $ic = IntlCalendar::createInstance('UTC'); $ic->setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(4); $ic->setFirstDayOfWeek(IntlCalendar::DOW_MONDAY); $use_formatter->setCalendar($ic) to enable weekday and week number based on ISO 8601.
